# Should I choose "I already belong to a museum" or "I belong to a museum already"?

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, word-order

Is this sentence grammatical and semantic correct?

> I feel like I **already** belong to a museum!

or

> I feel like I belong to a museum **already**!

or it should be something completely different?

Comment: Whereabouts you place **already** makes no grammatical difference to a puzzling statement.  People don't normally **belong** to museums, at least not until they're dead and mummified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of *belonging to a museum* isn't a common one.

As a native speaker, this would probably prompt me to ask you:

1. Do you mean that you feel like you are living as an exhibit in a museum?

or,

2. Do you mean that you feel like you have a membership to a particular museum? (Many museums in the US offer yearly memberships to reduce the cost of entry to people who visit frequently.)

For the first case, I would say "I feel like I'm on display in a museum."

For the second case, I would say "I feel like I already have a membership to that museum, but I can't remember right now."

So - as your question stands currently, **no**, it isn't semantically correct because it is so ambiguous as to be unanswerable.

Edited after a sentence was cut off.

Comment: Welcome, Katie. This is a well thought out and explained answer for a relative newcomer. ;)